# css not loading on postback

Tags: asp.net, css

On one of my asp.net page, when I access it, It loads and fetches data properly on default criteria. All styles for menu, search criteria controls and gridView controls displays perfectly.

When I click one of the buttons that postback the form and loads data, styles are gone. All styles vanished.

Looking through developer tools and going to CSS tab, all my stylesheets under App_theme are loaded properly on first time access **but** on postback, when I check through developer tools, No CSS loaded :(

Any idea?

**Note:** 
I am using a masterpage that contains the html form.
I tested on IE version 10 and 8.
First time loading loads all CSS perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your markup where you are attaching css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firebug tool in FF to check if there are any 404 error while loading CSS after form postbacks.

If yes, check the path of CSS that is showing 404 error.

Comment: My site is only for IE and facing the issue on IE versions.

Comment: Hi guys,
I resolved the issue myself. There was a mistake.

Actually, Page_PreInit method has a check for Postback while applying Page Theme as

if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
 Page.Theme = "MyTheme";
}

That's why its not assigning theme on Postback.

Thanks.